# Из текстового файла в строки C#

Tags: c#, строки, файлы

Допустим есть текстовый файл, в котором в каждой строке лежит слово и последовательность цифр. Как мне поместить в одну строку только слова, а в другую - только цифры?

Пример файла:

```
testText0 1 2 3 4
testText1 2 4
```

Comment: То есть у вас гарантировано буквы, потом пробел, потом цифры в каждой строке? Или может быть ещё что-то? Дайте пример текста.

Comment: testText0 1 2 3 4
testText1 2 4(построчно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме решений в лоб всегда остаётся вариант использования [регулярных выражений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
........
var Lines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFileName.txt");
var RegEx = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z]+)([\d\s]+)$");
var Words = new List<String>();
var Digits = new List<String>();

foreach (var Line in Lines){
    var Matches = RegEx.Match(Line);
    Words.Add(Matches.Groups[1].ToString());
    Digits.Add(Matches.Groups[2].ToString());
}
```

Этот подход хорош еще и тем, что он автоматически валидирует входные данные.

Проверить регулярные выражения можно [тут](http://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Ну например как-то так:

```
var digits = "0123456789".ToArray();
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
var linesWithBreakingIndices =
    lines.Select(line => new { line, index = line.IndexOfAny(digits) }).ToList();
var justWords = string.Join(" ",
                    linesWithBreakingIndices.Select(li => li.line.Substring(0, li.index)));
var justDigits = string.Join(" ",
                    linesWithBreakingIndices.Select(li => li.line.Substring(li.index)));
```

---

Вариант без LINQ:

```
var digits = "0123456789".ToArray();
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
StringBuilder justWordsBuilder = new StringBuilder(),
              justDigitsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var first = true;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var index = line.IndexOfAny(digits);
    if (!first)
    {
        justWordsBuilder.Append(' ');
        justDigitsBuilder.Append(' ');
    }
    justWordsBuilder.Append(line, 0, index);
    justDigitsBuilder.Append(line, index, line.Length - index);
    first = false;
}
var justWords = justWordsBuilder.ToString();
var justDigits = justDigitsBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: спасибо, правда LINQ пока не знаю, но попробую разобраться

Comment: @РустемВалеев: Добавил вариант без LINQ. Но вы всё же выучите LINQ, без него никуда.